# Kubernetes - connect to Azure SQL using Active Directory ID

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-aks, istio

We have an AKS POD (.NET 6 application) which can successfully connect to an Azure SQL database with SQL Server auth - user and password.

However, when used with an Active Directory ID, it throws a remotecertificatename mismatch error. This AKS cluster has istio configured. If used with a cluster which doesn't have Istio enabled, I can connect using Active Directory ID and password.

I tried adding service entries with `*.database.windows.net`, destination rule with tls disabled, none of these work. I validated certificate against digicert utility page, and certificatename matches. So, not sure where the mismatch issue is coming from.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone, we were able to resolve it by adding istio service entries for ports 80, 443 of sts.windows.net and port 443 of login.windows.net and login.microsoftonline.net. It was quite an issue!!